# get_internal_error() returns CharField instead of EmailField & URLField

Tags: python, django

I have fields in `models.py` which are `EmailField` and `URLField`. When I call `get_internal_type()` on these the method returns `CharField` instead of `EmailField` and `URLField`.

I want it to be `EmailField` and `URLField` for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to special-case these types, use the name of the class instead:

```
type(field).__name__  # get name of the field class, instead of field.get_internal_type()
```

Both `EmailField` and `URLField` *are* `Charfield` subclasses, just with a maximum length pre-set and a dedicated validator.